# Не сохраняются настройки игры при переходе на другую сцену

Tags: unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI; //Работа с интерфейсами
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement; //Работа со сценами
using UnityEngine.Audio; //Работа с аудио
public class mainsetting : MonoBehaviour
{
public Dropdown Resolution;
public AudioMixer audioMixer;
Resolution[] resolutions;
void Start()
{
    resolutions = Screen.resolutions;
    Resolution.ClearOptions();
    List<string> options = new List<string>();
    int currentResolutionIndex = 0;
    for (int i =0; i< resolutions.Length; i++)
    {
        string option = resolutions[i].width + "x" + resolutions[i].height;
        options.Add(option);

        if (Screen.resolutions[i].width == Screen.currentResolution.width &&
            Screen.resolutions[i].height == Screen.currentResolution.height)
        {
            currentResolutionIndex = i;
        }
    }
    Resolution.AddOptions(options);
    Resolution.value = currentResolutionIndex;
    Resolution.RefreshShownValue();
}
public void SetResolution (int resolutionIndex)
{
    Resolution resolution = resolutions[resolutionIndex];
    Screen.SetResolution(resolution.width, resolution.height, Screen.fullScreen);
}
public void SetVolume (float volume)
{
    audioMixer.SetFloat("MyExposedParam", volume);
}
public void SetQuality (int qualiyIndex)
{
    QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(qualiyIndex);

}
public void SetFullscreen (bool isFullscreen)
{
    Screen.fullScreen = isFullscreen;
}
}
```

Есть скрипт с изменением "Разрешения экрана", "графики", "Звука", "полного экрана". Само меню сделано на одной сцене, а уровень игры на другой, при переходе на сцену уровня и назад в меню, у меня слетают настройки всех этих компонентов. Есть какое-то решение?

Comment: так записывай в PlayerPrefs настройки например, и перед загрузкой сцены устанавливай их

Comment: Покажите как вы их сохраняйте